# Unable to create global array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am trying to make a global array of structs, however the way in which I thought I would go about this doesn't work. For the application I need requires it be be global however will not know the size until inside the main() function. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//
struct player {
    char letter;
};

struct player *players;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    check _variables();
    int *inpBuff;
    inpBuff = convert_input(argv[1], argv[2]);
    int numPlayers = inpBuff[0];
    players =  malloc(numPlayers*sizeof(player));
    return 1;
}
```

I receive the error:
    error: 'player' undeclared (first use in this function)
      players =  malloc(numPlayers*sizeof(player));

Comment: The struct is called `struct player`.

Comment: @immibis I'm new to C can you please let me know what does `char** argv` works for? why two `**` after char?

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil Here is a link for better understanding: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/

Comment: @user10334659 Thanks for sharing, will have a look! :)

Comment: `1` is not a portable exit status. On at least one system it means "success", but on Unix/Windows it is an error code. The portable return values of `main` are `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` for success and `EXIT_FAILURE` for failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOURCE OF ERROR-->** You are using **player** instead of **players** in malloc which is incorrect. Player is the name of `struct` and you need the pointers name in `malloc`.

First --> You need to correct your `malloc` statement --> use `players = malloc(numPlayers*(sizeof(*players));`

Second --> When return type of `main()` function is `int` then your `return` statement seems to be missing.

Comment: The first point you made didn't stop me from receiving the error:
error: 'player' undeclared (first use in this function) players = malloc(numPlayers*sizeof(player));

As for you second point this is because I only posted a snippet of the code and forgot the return.

Comment: `return` is optional in `main`. Since C99, running off the end of `main` automatically returns `0`.